# python lambda raises variable not defined error with multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

When trying to write a one line Fibonacci sequence that I understand, I'm having an issue with `fib = lambda a, b: b, a + b` as `"'b' is not defined"`

However, when I do `sum = a, b, c: a + b + c` I get no errors.  `sum(1, 2, 3)` runs perfectly and returns `6`.

I've researched global variables and found that if I set a and b to Null before starting, it doesn't give me an error, but is there a way not to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around the lambda body:

```
fib = lambda a, b: (b, a + b)
```

Otherwise Python thinks it is this:

```
fib = (lambda a, b: b), a + b
```

Incidentally, there's no real purpose in using `lambda` if you're just going to assign the function to a name.